Ethnic private chat group in a workplace
I have created an ethnic private chat group on our company's MS Teams platform. I've added coworkers who belong to the same country. We post chat messages about our festivals, politics, major game leagues, etc. One participant has expressed concern this group could be foreseen as violating DEI. Does anyone else foresee it to be the case? If so, what steps should I take next?

We wouldn't have any idea. Why don't you ask your management?

What would you do if someone of a different ethnicity tried to join, saying they were interested in the culture of country X?

“Does anyone else foresee it to be the case?” - Yes; Would you have a problem if someone was excluding you from their group due to your ethnicity? It’s essentially troublesome if you are in any sort of leadership position.

Just because what the OP is suggesting is a bad idea doesn't make this a bad question. +1

I have a certain amount of sympathy for this question. I'm an immigrant myself, and sometimes I just want to hang out with people from my old country, and talk about things we all share but which people here don't know about. But it's definitely about my country, not my ethnicity.

@DJClayworth I haven't downvoted, but one of the stated questions is whether a company policy might be violated, which we have no way of answering without knowing that policy. The answers mostly seem to be about whether it is a good idea independent of policies. It should be possible to rephrase the question in a way that does not invalidate the answers. In that case I would likely upvote.

What would your approach be if someone that was not part of the culture wanted to join the chat? Maybe they have an interest in the culture, maybe their partner is that culture? Or maybe they have no reason stated. Would you exclude them? That's what it boils down to.

Please also note that apart from the ethnicity angle, what you are doing here is essentially creating a chat group at work using work resources to chat about non work topics. Of course veryone chats about non work topics but in general management won't be too keen to support you with that.

@GregoryCurrie If someone of another culture, country or ethnicity gets to know and would like to join, they'd be more than welcome to.

@Anonyma i've edited my question to exclude the "company policy" part and put it in context of general DEI.

Fight isolation, isolate yourself. Brain where?

As others have said, this is a bad idea. Excluding people based on ethnicity is never going to look good.
You can however easily fix this by changing "ethnicity" to "culture". Even "country" would be better than "ethnicity". Assuming you are genuinely wanting to talk about culture, politics and sport of country X, then instead of saying "this is for people of ethnicity X" you say "this is for people interested in the culture of country X" (or countries X and Y). As long as you back that up by allowing people of an entirely different ethnicity but who are genuinely interested in the culture you will be fine.
However notwithstanding the above, having a word with HR is probably a good idea. There may be policy on this, or they way want to write some. Better to find out about any policy before you violate it.
Also don't forget that there may be people of your ethnicity who have never lived in your country and don't know anything about the culture, sport or politics of it. There may also be people who live in your country but aren't of your ethnicity.

Thank you DJ. I've rephrased my question to be country specific instead of ethnicity since that aligned more closely to my intent. Also to answer your other question - first, since the group is private it's not searchable. If someone of another culture, country or ethnicity gets to know and would like to join, they'd be more than welcome to.

@Megatron Please don't do that because it makes all the answers wrong and irrelevant, since they now don't answer the question as read. Please just put it back. Someone else might really want to start a group about ethnicity and they deserve an answer.

makes sense. Done!

Yes. I don't know what country you live in, but in my homeland, the United States, creating any sort of group or club that excludes people based on race or ethnicity is somewhere between seriously frowned on and illegal. You could very literally lose your job over this and be subject to law suits. Just don't. There is no conceivable benefit that would make it worth the risk.

Thank you Jay. I've rephrased my question to be country specific instead of ethnicity since that aligned more closely to my intent.

"This is a whites only group, for pure white people"
"This is an Aryan group, for those of pure Germanic stock"
"This is a Tutsu group, no Hutus allowed"
I trust that highlights what the issue is with this.

I get what you're trying to say but I would argue that "messages about our festivals, politics, major game leagues, etc" is very different from "for those of pure Germanic stock"

@mattfreake - It is not the content that is the issue - it is the exclusion along racial lines. Once you start excluding people based on Ethnicity or Race, it never ends well. I am absolutely using the most extreme examples possible, to make the point.

I've worked with plenty of NZ colleagues (I'm in the UK) who had groups based around NZ rugby, going to the Walkabout and talking about what they were going to do when the moved back home. None of the participants I know of have been involved in genocide yet.

@mattfreake But would HR or the judge hearing a discrimination lawsuit know that your motives were pure? Or care? Sure, you could SAY "we're just talking about rugby leagues". But someone who is not allowed in the group might well wonder if you're not really discussing plots against "inferior races". Even if your members all say, "hey, this was just about rugby leagues", if it WAS something sinister, what would you expect them to say?  And even if the original intent was something totally innocent, if at any point someone helps another member get a promotion ...

... you may have just crossed the line into illegal discrimination. Because now the club isn't JUST about discussing rugby leagues, it's also about conferring economic benefits on members, which are only available to people of the favored ethnic group.

@jay I wasn't very clear. I do think there's a problem with the group in the original post and I agree with what you say. I just think this answer, with it's echoes of genocides is unhelpfully hyperbolic

@mattfreake The point I was trying to make, and sorry if this wasn't clear, is not that I think the OP was plotting genocide. Rather, that he leaves himself open to be accused of plotting discrimination. (Genocide is a bit extreme, but then I assume you were exaggerating yourself.) Even assuming he has no such thing in mind, there could be unintentional discrimination -- like my example of a member helping another member to get a promotion. And he certainly could be accused of intending discrimination even if he had no such plans.

This thread is interesting. I'm wondering why no one took the part "private" chat into consideration...

@mattfreake - were those groups talking about NZ Rugby exclusive along racial lines? E.g. if a French or Irish Rugby fan who followed the NZ leagues wanted to join, would they be able to? That is the key difference. To clarify, I am absolutely being hyperbolic - but with a reason: discrimination on racial lines never ends well - regardless of how benign the intention might be.

@TheDemonLord I agree, it’s a slippery slope

I had a colleague who was aryan. He was Iranian, former Persian. His parents were Iranian, born Persian. His grandparents were Persian. Hitler was a clueless twat, just at the time it would have been too dangerous to tell him. And he wasn’t exactly tall, blonde and blue-eyed either :-)

Your colleague is right, excluding people out of a group on the basis of their ethnicity very likely to get you in trouble at work if someone brings it to the attention of HR. The severity of this trouble could vary between being told off and ordered to delete the group all the way to a disciplinary dismissal if your company happens to be particularly strict about these things.
I would probably just delete the group before it becomes a problem or at the very least take if off your work infrastructure, you could also make it a group based around X culture but open for anyone interested to join.

It also sounds like the OP is using work resources for a non-work group.  IMHO this seems to belong on any other external social media platform.

Anna, thanks for the direction. @PeterM how do you casually group chat with your coworkers on an external social media platform?

@Megatron There are many social media and messaging platforms that allow you to create group chats.  You all just need to sign up to one you all agree on and start chatting.  In other words, the same as what you are doing on Teams.
